# Python Error: IndexError list index out of range

Tags: python, dictionary, input, key

```
 file = open(selection, 'r')
 dict = {}
 with open(selection, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        dict[key] = values
 englishWord = dict.keys()
 spanishWord = dict.values()
```

Hello, 
I am working on a project where I have an file with spanish and english words. I am trying to take these words, and put them into a dictionary. The file looks like this:

library, la biblioteca
school, la escuela
restaurant, el restaurante
cinema, el cine
airport, el aeropuerto
museum, el museo
park, el parque
university, la universidad
office, la oficina
house, la casa

Every time I run the code, I get an error about the range. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you think the string `'library, la biblioteca'` will be split?

Comment: You should give split() an explicit argument. In this case "," seems like the correct choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have empty lines in your file, resulting in empty `items`-list:

```
dict = {}
with open(selection, 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        items = line.split()
        if items:
            key, values = items[0], items[1:]
            dict[key] = values
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to open the file first if you need with!
Also you need to specify what the character used for splitting needs to be, otherwise it splits on every whitespace and not on ',' as you want it to. 
This code works (assuming your file is called 'file.txt'):

```
dict = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split(',')
        print(items)
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        dict[key] = values
englishWord = dict.keys()
spanishWord = dict.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you don't have empty lines.

```
dict = {}
with open(selection, 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        items = line.split()
        if (len(items) > 1):
            if items:
                key, values = items[0], items[1:]
                dict[key] = values
```